# Split a continuous table across pages into separate tables in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-table

I am now working on a Macro to split a continuous across 2 pages into 2 separate tables in MS Word.

Do anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In order to even start answering this more information is required. What is the structure of the table? Where can it be split? Anywhere? Only between rows? What's the decision criteria? Normally, a Word table splits automatically - why is that not happening in this case? Or, if it is, why is the split not what you need? Please use the [edit] link below the question to put this information **in** the question.

Comment: @Sunny_Wong What is achieved by splitting the table that isn't achieved by applying the 'heading row' setting to the heading rows? Alternatively, if the table has heading rows and you really do need to split the table, you'd need to tell us which rows are the heading rows so they can be replicated. You should also be aware that, since Word uses the active printer to optimise the page layout, the split might not occur in the correct place when viewed on a computer using a different printer.

Comment: Hi all
Actually I am having a table to document a batch of pictures.
There are actually two columns in the table. Column 1 putting the pictures inside the cell. Column 2 putting a common contour bar which have to be merge along the whole page (Column 2).
Since the sizes of pictures are not the same, sometimes there are cells go across two pages.
I have fixed the problem by disabling "Row to Break Across Pages". 
But as I am struggling in split the table into two tables across pages for me to put the contour bar for each page

thanks